# Current division with more than two parallel resistor

Tags: current, current-divider

According to the current division rule, if two resistors R1 and R2 are parallel then  \$ I_{R1} = \frac{R2}{(R1 + R2)} \times  I \$ . In this case which resistance value should I pick for the numerator to find \$ I_{R2} \$?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: The equation is easy enough to find the resistive value:1/1/R1+1/R2+1/R3 = 900.9009 ohms. But this is meaningless because you have not defined a voltage source or load. Could you please clarify your question better. 900 ohm 1% resistors are common. Even to .1% at a low cost.

Comment: Why is my answer deleted?

Comment: First, find the parallel resistance of all three resistors. THEN use that resistance to calculate the voltage drop across all three resistors. THEN use that voltage to calculate the current in each resistor independently. Don't memorize some silly rule like the three resistor current sharing rule that you will only find once in your whole life.

Comment: @Sparky256, the current is shown on the diagram. Maybe you didn't notice. But it is 10 mA.

Comment: @mkeith. I was thinking in terms of not having a load, not in terms of silly calculations that are meaningless with no load, even if the current flow is defined. Sounds like something only a teacher would ask for.

Comment: @Sparky256, oh, I see your point. Since it is an open circuit, the listed current is actually impossible. True enough.

Comment: @mkeith. We could assume the voltage is so high the 10mA is leaking into the air...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2 resistor formula won't work because there are **3** resistors in parallel. The current goes through all 3 resistors, so first you must calculate the total resistance. The formula for *any* number of resistors in parallel is 1/Rt = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + ...

Once you have the total resistance you can multiply it by the total current to get the voltage drop. Once you have *that*, simply divide the voltage by each resistor's value to get the current flowing through it.

Answer (score 1):

In case of more than one parallel resistors, it is better to convert each resistance into conductance, and then the current division rule in parallel circuit is analogous to the voltage division rule in series circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of &Bruce Abbot's answer is more convenient in this case. If you really want to use current-division, that is possible too. You have to "make" (calculating the R2 || R3) two resistor from your three and apply the current-division rule twice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1jGxz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First you determine \$ I^* \$ (which is the current flowing through \$ R^* \$ ) in the first circuit, then apply current-division for \$ R_1 \$ and \$ R^* \$.

Once you know \$ I^* \$, you can use it to apply a second current-division on the second circuit for \$ R_2 \$ and \$ R_3 \$, calculating let's say the current flowing through \$ R_3 \$, which is \$ I_3 \$.

\$ I_2 = I^* - I_3 \$

\$ I_1 = I_{in} - I^* \$

Answer (score 0):

Current division for any number of parallel resistors:
$$ I_X = I_T\ \times\ \frac {R_T} {R_X}$$
where:

- \$ I_X \$ - branch current.
- \$ I_T \$ - current entering branches.
- \$ R_X \$ - branch resistance.
- \$ R_T \$ - equivalent resistance of parallel circuit.

Test.  \$ R_T = 1k\Omega \ \parallel\ 10\Omega \ \parallel\ 100\Omega = 900.9\Omega\$

\$I_1 = I_T\ \times\ \frac {R_T} {R_1} = 10mA\ \times\ \frac {900.9\Omega} {1k\Omega} = 9.009mA\$
\$I_2 = I_T\ \times\ \frac {R_T} {R_2} = 10mA\ \times\ \frac {900.9\Omega} {10k\Omega} = 0.9009mA\$
\$I_3 = I_T\ \times\ \frac {R_T} {R_3} = 10mA\ \times\ \frac {900.9\Omega} {100k\Omega} = 0.09009mA\$
\$I_T = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 9.009mA + 0.9009mA + 0.09009mA = 9.99999mA = 10mA\$

Answer (score 0):

First find the equivalent resistance of all three resistors which are connectd in parallel combination.then use that resistance to calculate the voltage drop across all resistors.Then use that voltage to calculate the current across each resistors...as voltage across each resistor is same in parallel combination...